# Post with Rest Api to ODL controller

Tags: javascript, rest, opendaylight

I'm new with OpenDaylight controller ,I'm getting this error when trying to post with Rest api to OpenDaylight.

```
function UserAction() {

var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

xhttp.open("POST", "http://localhost:8181/restconf/config/SecAser:SecAser/", 
false);
xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
var parameters={
"attacks": [
{
"id":"4",
"attack-match":"Sniffing",
"etat":"true"
}
]
}
//JSON.stringify(parameters);
xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
xhttp.send(parameters);
var response = JSON.parse(xhttp.responseText);
alert(xhttp.responseText);
}
```

This is the datasource [image: like a database]]
[image: and this is the error message]

Comment: May be you can call stringfy for posting. Plus share your YANG model for better understanding

Answer (score 1):

It's done with structure

```
var parameters ='{"attacks":[{"id":'+getRandomInt(35,45)+',"attack-match":"Sniffing","etat":true}]}';



xhttp.send(parameters);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find examples of commonly-used REST requests in these [OpenDaylight Netvirt Postman collections](https://git.opendaylight.org/gerrit/gitweb?p=netvirt.git;a=tree;f=resources/commons;h=edff6678d952dba5c620b6a24d244048ce710497;hb=HEAD).